# javax.net.ssl.SSLException with Facebook SDK, Android

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

In my device default facebook application is working fine, but when i try to login with facebook from my application it gives me below error.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake returned an invalid session. Socket state (closed, connected, bound, input_open, output_open, graph.facebook.com/31.13.79.81)

I try to search lot about that but none of the solution works.

Any help on this is really appreciated.